# How to create custom UIAlertView that has a checkbox with 3 buttons on iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uialertview

I want to create a popup dialog which has a label, checkbox (not Switch) and 3 buttons. I would also want to customize the font, text and color of the text and buttons. Is subclassing UIView a better option than subclassing UIAlertView?

Comment: What do you exactly ask? UIAlertView is already inherits from UIView http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIAlertView is pretty limited. Use a normal UIView, and present that modally. Or use a UIAlertView replacement such as [TSAlertView](https://github.com/TomSwift/TSAlertView)

Comment: I'll have a look at this class and see if I can reuse this one.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, you should subclass UIView to create a nice customizable popup dialog. I did that for one of my app and it really works like a charm.
To have a similar popup effect as the UIAlertView, I use 3 animations. The first changes the scale of the view from 0.001 to 1.1, second one goes to 0.9 and the last one to a scale of 1. All animations last .3 seconds
And there you have it !